# Bootstrap active tab not deactivating properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm fairly new to twitter bootstrap and inherited a project that I'm trying to debug. My issue is, I have a dropdown menu nested inside a navbar. The items on the dropdown menu correspond to some tabbed content. I want the first item in the that dropdown to default to active along with its corresponding tab content. I can get this to work, but the issue then becomes when clicking a different menu item, the initial item remains "active". It's only after clicking a 3rd item, does the 1st/default item become properly deactivated.

Here is the code and an a JSFiddle.

```
<div id="content" class="container">
    <div template="header" id="header">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Stats <b class="caret"></b></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#lastday" id="id_day" data-toggle="tab">Last 24 hours</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class=""><a href="#sevendays" id="id_week" data-toggle="tab">Last 7 days</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class=""><a href="#thirtydays" id="id_month" data-toggle="tab">Last 30 days</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div template="dash" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane  main-content" id="sevendays">
            <div class="offset1 span4">
                <h2>7 Days</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane  main-content" id="thirtydays">
            <div class="offset1 span4">
                <h2>30 Days</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane  main-content active" id="lastday">
            <div class="offset1 span4">
                <h2>24 Hours</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hKQA8/

Note how when you click on STATS the 7 DAYS content is selected as is its associated tab. If you then click on 24 HOURS, its associated tab becomes selected. However, if you go back to the dropdown you will see that both 7 DAYS and 24 HOURS remain highlighted/active. It's only after clicking the 3rd item that things start working normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my boss took some time to look this over with me and he came up with the solution. It turns out that because the tab menu is nested beneath another menu, you have to set that parent menu's item to "active" as well and then the issue goes away. Here is the updated JSFiddle in case someone else runs into the issue.

```
<li class="dropdown active">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hKQA8/3/